# crosstool-ng build fails: CT_TARGET command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi2, crosstool-ng

I am trying to build a cross compiler for raspberry pi. I am using crosstool-ng to build this compiler. I am following this link for reference. I have made all configurations as told in the [link](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426). But when i tried to build, I am getting "CT_TARGET command not found" error. I tried googling about the error couldn't able to find any hits. Could someone help me in overcoming this issue? Here is the complete build output.

```
/opt/cross/bin$ sudo ct-ng build
/opt/cross/bin/.config.2: line 30: CT_TARGET: command not found
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: source[/opt/cross/bin/.config.2@30]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@25]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/opt/cross/share/doc/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.21.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 24087567:26.24)
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made a mistake entering the configuration options.
You need to make sure that you put a $ symbol in front of CT_TARGET:

```
$CT_TARGET
```

or else it thinks it is a command that will return the value it wants.
Posting your exact config instead of the website you got the instructions from would provide much more details to solve your specific issue.